# What to do when a touch-up paint job goes bad because you applied brush strokes instead of dabs?

Tags: paint, repainting

I was patching a few spots on my already finished wall for 10 years this week. It is drywall. I used brush strokes in the painting phase of the touch up but didn't know that this was going to leave a gloss noticeable from an angle.

After some research [videos like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZ4sM03QWPY&ab_channel=howtopaintinfo) explain that strokes leave this noticeable glare but dabs would solve the problem and helps match the original roller texture. Now that I already screwed it up and not wanting to screw it up a second time, I'm reaching out this time prior to my next move.

Simply put:
How do you fix when a touch up goes bad? specifically in the context of using brush strokes over dabs?

Do I need to scrape off the previous paint? apply another coat of spackle? dab over the previous coat?

P.S.
Another draw back of using brush strokes is that, it tends to make the touch up bigger. I think the spot is maybe 10x bigger because of brush strokes. So PSA: Don't brush stroke touch ups!

Answer (score 1):

Allow the paint to cure, sand flat then repaint with a roller, (you can get a small sponge roller for a few dollars)

Comment: What do you think of the brush dabbing methods noted in the videos or this paper towel method in this video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5tBrVJGlwyU&ab_channel=EspressoYourself  What grit sand paper do you recommend? 80 grit? Thanks for any insight

Comment: it needs to be fine enough to not tear up the paint. maybe 200 grit depending on how long the paint has been curing for. latex paint takes about 30 days to fully harden.